# NginX and Galera Cluster are friends?

Tags: nginx, cluster, mariadb, galera

So I've found NginX's official tutorial, how to use NginX Plus as the proxy for the MariaDB Cluster. However, if I do this with my standard NginX (not the Plus edition) I constantly get the error
`nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/conf.d/mariadb.conf:10`

Here is the config

```
upstream db {
    server 10.0.0.101:3306;
    server 10.0.0.102:3306;
    server 10.0.0.103:3306;
}

server {
    listen 3306;
    location / {
        proxy_pass db;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    }
}
```

My question if this is only available on NginX Plus or I'm doing something wrong? I'm aware, that normally I need a prefix in the proxy_pass like `https://` but in this case?

Comment: Please post the output from `nginx -T`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `location / {}` stuff. This is for http servers, not for plain TCP. And you need to wrap it into a `stream` block.

```
stream {
    upstream db {
        server 10.0.0.101:3306;
        server 10.0.0.102:3306;
        server 10.0.0.103:3306;
    }

    server {
        listen 3306;
        proxy_pass db;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    }
}
```

You can find the documentation here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Comment: If I do that, then the error message changes to: `"proxy_pass" directive is not allowed here`. I've included the location because of this specific reason. :/ Also, the stream is included in `nginx.conf` and inside stream I've written `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`

Comment: I guess then this really is only possible with NginX Plus. I never used it that way, so I can't tell for sure.

Comment: This should work fine, provided nginx is 1.9.0 or higher. Something else is wrong with the config, most likely. Look at `nginx -T`.